# Multiprocessing with Python, locking variables

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create two processes. Each of them is writing 10 times into an 
array which has a length of 20. Both processes access the **same** array.
One process writes as soon as he can, the other has to wait a little before he can write.

My problem is, I cant lock those variables to prevent race conditions.
Is it even possible on a multicore system?
And also I would like to get the array full. At this state, only the first ten slots of the array get written.

Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, RawValue, RawArray, Value, Array, Lock
from ctypes import c_int

def write1(field):
    counter = 0
    global position
    for position in range(len(field)):
        if counter < 10:
            field[position] = 1
            counter += 1
            position += 1


def write2(field):
    counter = 0
    global position
    for position in range(len(field)):
        for i in range(40):
            if i == (40-1):
                if counter < 10:
                    field[position] = 2
                    counter += 1
                    position += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    field = Array(c_int, range(20), lock = True)
    position = Value(c_int, 0, lock = True)

    p1 = Process(target=write1,args=(field,))
    p2 = Process(target=write2,args=(field,))
    p2.start()
    p1.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(field[:])
    print('done')
```

**EDIT**

I found the solution. I had to use a seperate lock object to lock up my Array.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, RawValue, RawArray, Value, Array, Lock
from ctypes import c_int

def write1(field, lock):
    counter = 0
    global position
    with lock:
        for position in range(len(field)):
            if counter < 10:    
                field[position] = 1
                counter += 1

def write2(field, lock):
    counter = 0
    global position
    with lock:
        for position in range(len(field)):
            for i in range(40):
                if i == (40-1):
                    if counter < 10:
                        field[position] = 2
                        counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    field = Array(c_int, range(20))
    position = Value(c_int, 0)

    p1 = Process(target=write1,args=(field,lock))
    p2 = Process(target=write2,args=(field,lock))
    p2.start() 
    p1.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(field[:])
    print('done')
```

But I have still the problem that what is written by one process, the other one will overwrite.

Comment: What is your problem? As you are already using the Array-class of the multiprocessing-module, race conditions are prevented automatically. And the full array gets written when `counter < 10` is changed to `counter < 20`.

Comment: That's what I also thought, that a simple Array would be sufficient. You can look at my edit, I solved it. Now to other problem. If i use **counter < 20** the whole array will be written by only one process 20 times. My goal is that every process writes 10 times each.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did not think that the additional lock would be necessary as it should be handled automatically by the `sharedctypes`-module. Maybe I misunderstood the documentation.